# Image displays in Visual Studio and Report Builder -- but not in SSRS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I've inherited a couple of reports that were developed in Visual Studio 2008. I've been asked to upload them to the SSRS Report Manager so people can maintain them in Report Builder. One of the two reports uploads with no problem, but...

On one of the reports, the images (embedded) don't display in SSRS, I see placeholders instead. But the weird thing is that if I proceed to Report Builder, the images are there! Which suggests to me that the images must be there in SSRS as well, but SSRS is not displaying them, for some reason. And since the images ***are*** displaying on the other report, it can't be a problem with my global SSRS configuration. (Right?)

Apologies in advance if some of my terminology is confusing, I'm ***very*** new to all of this.

Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: I understand your situation, but: what's the question? (Note that you can edit your question to update it.)

Answer (score 0):

Do the images have any code behind them? 
I have the following code and it shows up OK in SSRS & RB 3.0, RB2.0

System.Convert.FromBase64String(Mid(System.Convert.
 ToBase64String(Fields!Picture.Value),105))